# What ayatori pattern did Yukko make that made Mai-chan shocked in Episode 17?

Tags: nichijou

In episode 17, Yukko trying to stop *tsukkomi*-ing Mai. At the end of this scene, there is a part where Yukko made an [*ayatori*](http://web-japan.org/nipponia/nipponia26/en/topic/index02.html) (a traditional Japanese game for children) like below:

[image: ayatori]

And after that, Mai-chan seems to be shocked.

[image]

What pattern is this? What's the meaning of it?

Relevant video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXNYAJLxHFE).

Comment: Could she just be surprised at the shape being made, if it's a really hard pattern or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This apparently the "[Gunma prefecture with the shape of a soaring crane](https://www.visitgunma.jp/en/about/index.html)" （鶴舞う形の群馬県）. You may not know this but the shape of the prefecture somewhat resembles a crane flapping its spread wings.

The purpose is likely to add absurdity as so many people heard the tsukkomi she put all of her heart in. Take note that the school is based on the high school the original creator attended, Isesaki Commercial High School [located in the Gunma prefecture](http://nichijou.wikia.com/wiki/Gunma_Prefecture). This seems to be a meta joke on how the tsukkomi was loud, everyone in the Gunma prefecture heard her.

[image: 鶴が飛んでいるようなカタチ]

[image: ご当地ゆるキャラを勝手に考案して、きせかえにしちゃっても面白いかな、とか思ってます]

[image: 県の形についてである。 群馬県の人たちは、自らの県の形が鶴に似て.]